# Adapt a class method to another class

Tags: python, django

```
 @python_2_unicode_compatible
 class EmployerProfile(AbstractAddress):
      customer = models.OneToOneField(
          CustomerProfile, verbose_name=_('Customer'),
          related_name='employerprofile')
      company_name = models.CharField(_('Company name'),
                                        max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
            ...

    #That function will empty all fields in this model whenever income_source
    # is different of 'Employed'
    def empty_fields(self):
        if self.income_source != 'Employed':
            to_empty = [f.name for f in EmployerProfile._meta.get_fields()]
            exclude = [u'id', "has_missing_fields",
                       "manual_validation", "actor_actions",
                       "target_actions", "action_object_actions",
                       ]
        for field_name in to_empty:
            if field_name not in exclude:
                setattr(self, field_name, None)

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class FinancialProfile(models.Model):
    customer = models.OneToOneField(
        CustomerProfile, verbose_name=_('Customer'),
        related_name='financialprofile')
    income_source = models.CharField(_('Income source'), max_length=20,
                                     choices=settings.LOANWOLF_INCOME_SOURCE_CHOICES,
                                     default='employed')
```

I would like to move `empty_field()` in the class `FinancialProfile`. In fact, this method must emptied the attributes from `EmployerProfile` whenever income_source (FinancialProfile) != 'Employed'. Could anyone be able to tell me how could I do such thing?

**P.S.** Please tell me if there's something unclear.

Thanks!

Comment: Wasn't this question asked a while ago?...and don't delete unsolved questions, just ask again after a few days if no one looked at it, deleting is not a good habit

Comment: Yes, but we remove comments.